# I want to find difference between expiry time and and current time of QRcode generation and qrcode verification time. 2min exp time and store in db

Tags: mysql, nest, prisma

`
//I m using prisma in nest js
//QRcode generate and store in the db(mysql)
const date = new Date(); // create a new date object
const expiryDate = new Date().getTime()+ 120000; // add 120 seconds to the date

```
    // insert data for qrcode
    let qrcode_data = await tx.attendanceQrcode.create({
      data: {
        application_name: createAttendanceQrCodeDto.application_name,
        application_version: createAttendanceQrCodeDto.application_version,
        expiry_period: new Date(expiryDate),
        public_key: hash,
        shift_id: getUserSiteInfo.ShiftAssignSite.shift_id,
        site_id: getUserSiteInfo.ShiftAssignSite.site_id,
        sub_site_id: getUserSiteInfo.ShiftAssignSite.sub_site_id,
      },
    });
```

//verify qrcode here

let checkPublicKeyExistance =
await this.prisma.attendanceQrcode.findFirst({
where: {
public_key: public_key,
},
});
if (!checkPublicKeyExistance) {
return "public key does't match";
}
console.log("checkPublicKeyExistance.expiry_period ",checkPublicKeyExistance.expiry_period)

```
  let currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  let qrcodeValidityTime = checkPublicKeyExistance.expiry_period.getTime();
  
  if (currentTime > qrcodeValidityTime) {
    return 'Qrcode expired. Please generate qr again';
  }
  return true;
```

`

current time is always greater than expiry time. I checked in console.